# Programmatically set current-menu-item using wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, navigation

I'm calling [`wp_nav_menu`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) programmatically on a class and I'd like to be able to set the field that will be shown as the `current-menu-item` but I don't see an argument for that.

It seems like I may be able to use [`nav_menu_css_class`?](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_css_class)

Comment: Use a custom walker for total control - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_custom_Walker_class

Comment: I'd really prefer to use something more lightweight than a custom walker... But if I need to I will.

Answer (score 0):

[Adding Conditional Classes to Menu Items](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items)

> This example would let you add a custom class to a menu item based on the condition you specify. Don't forget to change the condition.

```
<?php
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'special_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function special_nav_class($classes, $item){
     if(is_single() && $item->title == "Blog"){ //Notice you can change the conditional from is_single() and $item->title
             $classes[] = "special-class";
     }
     return $classes;
}
?>
```

Also take a look at [How to Add a Custom Class to a WordPress Menu Item](http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item).